# How come my Grub isn't initialised at the boot?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, kali-linux, boot-loader

I dual booted Kali next to Windows7 and after a succesfull install I rebooted to not find an option to use Kali instead of Win7 in the BIOS.

After having done some research I found out that Win7 has a tendency to uninstall GRUB.
So looking into that I rebooted using my live usb with kali on it and tried to solve my problem by trying to reinstall GRUB using the explanation here ,and adjusted the sda3 to sda6 since this is where I have kali installed on my harddrive:
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7

```
root@kali:~# mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
root@kali:~# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
root@kali:~# mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
root@kali:~# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
root@kali:~# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
root@kali:~# chroot /mnt
root@kali:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@kali:/# update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4
done
root@kali:/# exit
exit
root@kali:~# umount /mnt/dev/pts
root@kali:~# umount /mnt/dev
root@kali:~# umount /mnt/proc
root@kali:~# umount /mnt/sys
root@kali:~# umount /mnt
```

I remove the live usb and reboot my computer while holding shift but it goes back to the windows bootloader.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: After reboot you need to update the grub to add WIndows partition (per your link): `os-prober`
`update-grub`Have you done this already?

Comment: No I hadn't . I tried it now but I got this: bash: os-prober: command not found

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install os-prober`

Comment: Ok ,that worked. Now I got this after having to sudo apt-get install grub:
root@kali:~# update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... 
No GRUB directory found.
 To create a template run 'mkdir /boot/grub' first.
 To install grub, install it manually or try the 'grub-install' command.
 ### Warning, grub-install is used to change your MBR. ###

Comment: Just create the directory. That seems more painless than doing a grub-install...

Comment: Ok ,than rerunned and got this:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Rebooted computer while holding shift ,still nothing

Comment: If you are using multiple disks, is the device/disk with GRUB installed in MBR listed as the first boot option in BIOS?